# Swap attributes in tags using Visual Studio 2008 RegEx

Tags: visual-studio, regex, visual-studio-2008, replace

How to swap attributes `ID` and `runat` in all tags in my Visual Studio 2008 solution?

Was

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
```

became

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" />
```

Comment: Is this the same as this question you posted minutes earlier...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180292/find-tags-doesnt-contain-specific-attribute-specific-word-using-visual-studio

Comment: @tommieb75: no, this is not the same. is is about swapping and that is about searching a string doesn't contain a word. Both just about the same topic - visual studio regex. I wanted to ask both of them long time ago and asked them just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Find and Replace, enable Use of Regular expressions.

Find what:

```
 ID="{[^\"]+}" runat="server"
```

Replace with:

```
 runat="server" ID="\1"
```

Use {} to tag sub-expressions within regular expression. The meaning of find part is: find one or more characters that aren't quotation marks after ID=" and up to next quotation mark and tag it as sub-expression.

In replace, you use \1 to denote the first sub-expression found and that's the tag id.

Edit: Add a single space character in front of search and replace expressions, to avoid matching something like: `ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"`.

Comment: Thanks! That is very easy and exactly what I was searching for. P.S. The same result as 'find part' you can get inserting leading space to both expression: _ID=... => _runat=...